# C++ pragma GCC system_header directive

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

What this C++ directive do: "#pragma GCC system_header"?

Comment: Editors, can you modify the title to better reflect the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I googled and got [this](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/cpp/pragmas.html):

> `#pragma GCC system_header`
>
> ```
> This pragma takes no arguments. It causes the rest of the code in the
> current file to be treated as if it came from a system header. Section 2.7
> System Headers.
> ```

[More info on System headers](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/cpp/system-headers.html)

> 2.7. System Headers
>
> The header files declaring interfaces
>   to the operating system and runtime
>   libraries often cannot be written in
>   strictly conforming C. Therefore, GCC
>   gives code found in system headers
>   special treatment. All warnings, other
>   than those generated by #warning
>   (Chapter 5 Diagnostics), are
>   suppressed while GCC is processing a
>   system header. Macros defined in a
>   system header are immune to a few
>   warnings wherever they are expanded.
>   This immunity is granted on an ad-hoc
>   basis, when we find that a warning
>   generates lots of false positives
>   because of code in macros defined in
>   system headers.
>
> Normally, only the headers found in
>   specific directories are considered
>   system headers. These directories are
>   determined when GCC is compiled. There
>   are, however, two ways to make normal
>   headers into system headers.
>
> The -isystem command line option adds
>   its argument to the list of
>   directories to search for headers,
>   just like -I. Any headers found in
>   that directory will be considered
>   system headers.
>
> All directories named by -isystem are
>   searched after all directories named
>   by -I, no matter what their order was
>   on the command line. If the same
>   directory is named by both -I and
>   -isystem, the -I option is ignored. GCC provides an informative message
>   when this occurs if -v is used.
>
> There is also a directive, #pragma GCC
>   system_header, which tells GCC to
>   consider the rest of the current
>   include file a system header, no
>   matter where it was found. Code that
>   comes before the #pragma in the file
>   will not be affected. #pragma GCC
>   system_header has no effect in the
>   primary source file.
>
> On very old systems, some of the
>   pre-defined system header directories
>   get even more special treatment. GNU
>   C++ considers code in headers found in
>   those directories to be surrounded by
>   an extern "C" block. There is no way
>   to request this behavior with a
>   `#pragma`, or from the command line.

Comment: I duckduckwent and got this SO page.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken, but this link is useful, too: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/cpp/System-Headers.html#System-Headers

Answer (score 6):

It says that everything past this point is treated as if it were in a system header.  That means that all warnings other than #warning are suppressed