# How to disable warnings coming from missing header file

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

there is a warning that stops my program from being compiled. It comes from a header file, inside of my header file. And that header file is from third party. Is there a way to disable it so that the compilation goes successfully?

Comment: your program can't be successfully compiled if a header file is missing...

Comment: I would think you *should* get a compiler error.  Q: What happens if you create a dummy header file?  Does it then complain about missing definitions?

Comment: possible duplicate?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308523/how-to-eliminate-external-lib-third-party-warnings-in-gcc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867065/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-library-headers

Comment: Just remove any mention of the missing header. If you are still getting errors, continue removing corresponding lines from the source, until it compiles cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Visual Studio, in the project properties-> C/C++ ->General settings there is a warning level item. you can set this to a lower value but it is a better practice to diminish such warnings by solving them, not by hiding because they may cause troubles in future.

Answer (score 1):

For missing header file you should get compile time error not a warning, and you need to provide that missing header file, if you introduce a new header file which is missing function declaration which original header file got, that will again generate compile time error as far as i see! So you would have to provide declaration of those functions also.