# How can ignore bazel features like `treat_warnings_as_errors` only on some files?

Tags: c++, build, bazel, bazel-rules

I have a library like the following in my bazel build file for C++:

```
cc_library(
    name = "mylib",
    srcs = [
        "main.cpp",
        "file1.cpp",
        "file2.cpp",
        ...
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "main.h",
        "file1.h",
        "file2.h",
        ...
    ],
    features = [
        "treat_warnings_as_errors",
        "strict_warnings",
        "additional_warnings",
    ],
    deps = [
        "my_dependency1",
        "my_dependency2",
        "third_party_dependency",
        ...
    ],
)
```

I need the constraints specified in `features` to be applied to all source files, except to `third_party_dependency` which is used by `file1`.

What I tried was removing `file1` from `mylib`, putting it in a new library (i.e. `mylib2`) and then adding that lib to `mylib` as a dependency. The only problem is that I don't want the whole `file1` to scape from the constraints, only `third_party_dependency`.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I woder if I can try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308523/how-to-eliminate-external-lib-third-party-warnings-in-gcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this was creating a new library as a wrapper for `third_party_dependency` not to mess up with third party code and on that second library I just had to add `#pragma GCC system_header` on the header file so that my gcc compiler ignores that file.

redits for [How to eliminate external lib/third party warnings in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308523/how-to-eliminate-external-lib-third-party-warnings-in-gcc)