# How to ignore "-W" message on included third party libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, mingw, warnings

I often include external/third party libraries on my C++ projects, and almost everytime they contains -W warning message while compiling my code.

They are located on `lib/*` folders. Specifically on Makefile, that's what I include:

```
# Add .h and .hpp to the preprocessor build
HEADERS += $(wildcard lib/*.h)
HEADERS += $(wildcard lib/*.hpp)
HEADERS += $(wildcard lib/**/*.h)
HEADERS += $(wildcard lib/**/*.hpp)
HEADERS += $(wildcard lib/**/**/*.h)
HEADERS += $(wildcard lib/**/**/*.hpp)
HEADERS += $(wildcard src/*.h)
HEADERS += $(wildcard src/*.hpp)
HEADERS += $(wildcard src/**/*.h)
HEADERS += $(wildcard src/**/*.hpp)

# Add .c and .cpp files to the build
SOURCES += $(wildcard lib/*.c)
SOURCES += $(wildcard lib/*.cpp)
SOURCES += $(wildcard lib/**/*.c)
SOURCES += $(wildcard lib/**/*.cpp)
SOURCES += $(wildcard lib/**/**/*.c)
SOURCES += $(wildcard lib/**/**/*.cpp)
SOURCES += $(wildcard src/*.c)
SOURCES += $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
SOURCES += $(wildcard src/**/*.c)
SOURCES += $(wildcard src/**/*.cpp)

# FLAGS will be passed to both the C and C++ compiler
FLAGS +=
CFLAGS +=
CXXFLAGS += $(sort $(foreach HEADERS, $(HEADERS), -I$(dir $(HEADERS))))
```

Is it possible to specify (I'm using MingGW on Windows, so "gcc") that for that `lib/*` folder, ignore warning message? Keeping my code/compilation clean? Its pretty boring "mess" with others libraries warning why compiling and check status.

Comment: You can compile `lib/...` source files with different compiler flags and then link them with your own source files. If an error is generated in `lib/...` headers included in your source files, I think there's no clean solution (without `#pragma GCC diagnostic push`/`pop`).

Comment: @maxplus what do you mean compile them with different flags? The command is One...

Comment: @maxplus of course some of those headers will be added to my headers/sources files

Comment: Using `-isystem` instead of `-I` could help. If not, `#pragma`s are the next best option. Also you might like the [recursive wildcard function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18258352/2752075).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat why `-isystem` could help?

Comment: `-isystem` specifies a "system include directory", advising the compiler to not warn about things included from it, just as it wouldn't warn about the contents of its own standard library.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, mmm, it seems it "works" for different reasons. I mean: before, at every change in included files, it would recompile in cascade. now it seems it ignore some edits? in fact if I clean all and rebuild, it also consider warning of all included files (even with -isystem)

Comment: If you have `-MMD` somewhere, you'd need to change that to `-MD` to consider the "system" includes. But if `-isystem` doesn't work, then there's no point, and you need `#pragma`s.

Comment: I mean: now it seems that if I edit a file (hpp or cpp) that is included in other hpp, with -I it seems to recompile every files in cascade, now only the compilation unit of the edited file (even if its included in other files). is it normal?

Comment: Make doesn't by default know to rebuild a .cpp file when a .h it includes changes. To make that work, GCC has flags to emit tiny pieces of makefiles (`-M...` family of flags), which you then `-include` into the main makefile. If that worked for you at some point, then you must be passing `-MMD -MP` to GCC (or some similar flags, there are a few different ways of doing it), and `-MMD` doesn't consider system includes, for better build times. But `-MD` does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255766/discussion-between-markzzz-and-holyblackcat).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it seems not working anymore on GCC>12 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072374/can-i-suppress-all-warnings-when-including-a-specific-file/72072493#72072493

Comment: @markzzz I already showed you a testcase where it does suppress warnings on GCC 13, look in the chat. If it doesn't work for you, please add a [mcve].

Comment: Simply don't use libraries that produce tons of warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to suppress warnings for specific files by dividing the compilation into parts and applying different flags.

E.g.

```
# Your sources and headers
SRC_HEADERS := $(wildcard src/*.h) $(wildcard src/*.hpp) $(wildcard src/**/*.h) $(wildcard src/**/*.hpp)
SRC_SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/**/*.c) $(wildcard src/**/*.cpp)

# Third-party libraries' sources and headers
LIB_HEADERS := $(wildcard lib/*.h) $(wildcard lib/*.hpp) $(wildcard lib/**/*.h) $(wildcard lib/**/*.hpp) $(wildcard lib/**/**/*.h) $(wildcard lib/**/**/*.hpp)
LIB_SOURCES := $(wildcard lib/*.c) $(wildcard lib/*.cpp) $(wildcard lib/**/*.c) $(wildcard lib/**/*.cpp) $(wildcard lib/**/**/*.c) $(wildcard lib/**/**/*.cpp)

# FLAGS for your sources
SRC_FLAGS := 
SRC_CFLAGS :=
SRC_CXXFLAGS := $(sort $(foreach HEADERS, $(SRC_HEADERS), -I$(dir $(SRC_HEADERS))))

# FLAGS for third-party libraries (suppress all warnings using -w)
LIB_FLAGS := -w
LIB_CFLAGS := -w
LIB_CXXFLAGS := $(sort $(foreach HEADERS, $(LIB_HEADERS), -I$(dir $(LIB_HEADERS))))

# Targets and rules
...

# Rule for compiling your sources
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(SRC_FLAGS) $(SRC_CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# Rule for compiling third-party libraries
lib/%.o: lib/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(LIB_FLAGS) $(LIB_CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Note `-w` will suppress all warnings. If you want to selectively disable specific warnings, you can use specific flags like `-Wno-<specific-warning>`.

For library headers included in your source things are a little trickier.

One approach might be to use `#pragma`s to disable warnings where the header is included.

E.g.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wextra"
#include "lib/whatever.hpp"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

That might be a little tedious, but hopefully less tedious than addressing each individual warning in the included headers =)

Comment: The problem with the last approch (ignoring the tediuos fact) is that if a ext. library use its .hpp on .cpp, I need to edit the "original" src, which is not so good. At least, for the first compilation...