# Visual Studio 2015: No signed/unsigned mismatch warning in std::make_unique?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, warnings, unique-ptr, signedness

I just found a bug in my code and I am pretty baffled that it could happen, since it is a simple signed/unsigned mismatch - which should not happen at all, because I am compiling with warning level 4, warnings as errors. So I tried to reproduce it, which is pretty simple:

```
#include <memory>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass( unsigned ) {}
};
int main()
{
    MyClass* rawP = new MyClass(-1);                // issues a warning, as expected
    auto uniqueP = std::make_unique<MyClass>(-1);   // NO WARNING??!

    // silence the compiler
    rawP; 
    uniqueP;

    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm asking myself: What's the reason of this? Is it a bug in VS, or is it a general shortcoming of std::make_unique? Is there any way to fix it? (Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing a combination of several effects.

1. The call in your `main()` is perfectly legitimate because the `make_unique`
   template instantiation matches the signed data type you feed it.
2. The implementation of `make_unique` does not generate a warning because
   warnings are typically disabled inside system headers.
3. Visual Studio seems to be unable to detect the *potential* (but not
   *definite*) sign conversion issue inside `make_unique`.

In more detail:

### 1. The template instantiation is actually legitimate.

A typical implementation of `std::make_unique` looks like this (compare
[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)):

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

In your case, as you call `std::make_unique<MyClass>(-1)`, the template is
instantiated for a *signed* integer.  Hence, you do not get a warning in your
code because no unsigned/signed conversion happens.

### 2. System headers typically disable warnings.

**However**, you *could* rightfully expect a warning from the `make_unique`
implementation.  After all, when `new T(...)` is called with your signed
parameter, a signed/unsigned conversion still happens.  As a case in point, take
the following program:

```
#include <memory>

class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(unsigned) { }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline std::unique_ptr<T> custom_make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main()
{
  auto uniqueP = custom_make_unique<MyClass>(-1);
  (void) uniqueP;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this using GCC with `-Wsign-conversion`, I get the warning

> test.cpp: In instantiation of 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp> custom_make_unique(Args&& ...) [with T = MyClass; Args = {int}]':
>   test.cpp:17:48:   required from here
>   test.cpp:12:63: warning: conversion to 'unsigned int' from 'int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
>     return std::unique_ptr(new T(std::forward(args)...));

So the question is, why do you not get this warning for the `std::make_unique()`
implementation?  The answer is essentially that the compiler silences these
warnings for its system headers.  For example, the GCC version of the `<memory>`
header contains the pragma

```
#pragma GCC system_header
```

As soon as this pragma is present in a header file, the compiler no longer
reports the warnings for everything inside that header.  From
the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html):

> The header files declaring interfaces to the operating system and runtime
>   libraries often cannot be written in strictly conforming C.  Therefore, GCC
>   gives code found in system headers special treatment. All warnings, other than
>   those generated by ‘`#warning`’ (see Diagnostics), are suppressed while GCC is
>   processing a system header.

See also
[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478092/c-pragma-gcc-system-header-directive) for
more details.  Presumably a similar approach is taken by Visual Studio's
compiler (and as you wrote in your comment, the header temporarily reduces the
warning level).

### 3. Looks like you are encountering a VisualStudio limitation.

In the case of VisualStudio, there is also something else at work.  Note how the
GCC warning above says that there *may* be a sign conversion problem (depending
on what values users will *later* feed into `custom_make_unique`).  It appears
that VisualStudio can only warn if there is a *definite* sign conversion issue.
See the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(unsigned) { }

template <typename T>
void g(T val) { f(val); } // GCC issues a warning, VS does NOT

int main()
{
  f(-1); // GCC and VS issue a warning
  g(-1); // no conversion warning here (g<int> instantiated)
}
```

[Try it online.](http://rextester.com/FSFYW87911)

Comment: Wow, that's a comprehensive answer, thank you very much. I tried it with your `custom_make_unique()`, but it still doesn't issue a warning (even when also copy and paste a `custom_forward` and `custom_remove_reference` into my own code). At least I now have an idea what to look for.

Comment: Hm. It's possible that VisualStudio, in general, only manages to warn in cases where it can deduce that there _will_ be a sign conversion problem. In my GCC example above, the compiler is only able to deduce that there _may_ be a problem (depending on the values you later feed into `custom_make_unique`). So maybe you are running into a Visual Studio limitation as well.

Comment: Indeed, the `memory` header temporarily reduces the warning level to 3 with a `#pragma warning(push,3)`, which would explain the missing warning. Nevertheless, it does not explain why the `custom_make_unique()` also does not work.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I updated my answer (luckily rextester.com provides a VC++ compiler).